# JPanel and PaintComponent

Tags: java, swing

I am really having problems understanding how overriding the `paintComponent(Graphics g)` method works.

I have the following class:

```
public class DisplayDocs2 extends JPanel {
    ArrayList <BufferedImage> docList;
    BufferedImage imageCount;

    public DisplayDocs2(ArrayList docList){
        this.docList = docList;
    }

    public JPanel DisplayImage(){
        this.setLayout(new BoxLayout(this, BoxLayout.X_AXIS));

        for (int i = 0; i < docList.size(); i++){
            imageCount = docList.get(i);
        }
        return this;
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g){
        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.drawImage(imageCount, 0, 0, this);
    }
}
```

Whatever I try, if I have more than one image then the first image is always covered by the last one.

I want to use `BufferedImage`s because I want to be able to manipulate them afterwards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The behaviour you experiencing is the result of your code. The part:

```
        for (int i = 0; i < docList.size(); i++) {
            imageCount = docList.get(i);
        }
```

Sets the `imageCount` reference to the last element of the list, which the `paintComponent()` method draws.
So your first image is not covered, it is not painted at all.

If you want to draw all the images,

1. Remove the `for` cycle above and the `imageCount` attribute, they are unnecessary.
2. Put a code like this into your `paintComponent()`:

   ```
   super.paintComponent(g);
   int x = 0;
   for (BufferedImage img : docList) {
       g.drawImage(img, x, 0, this);
       x += img.getWidth();
   }
   ```

This will paint all your images next to each other.
(Note that the code will throw NullPointerException if the method `DisplayDocs2` is never called with a non-null parameter.

Comment: Thank you this (I think) is the root of my problem.  I am not able to call paintComponent directly so I am at a loss how to paint each image.

Comment: The `paintComponent()` is called by the Swing framework whenever a repaint of the component is needed. I've edited my answer to include a possible solution for drawing all the images.

Comment: I think this is working, thank you very much. the only problem being when I try to enlarge the window the image dissappears.

Answer (score 3):

> I am really having problems understanding how overriding the paintComponent(Graphics g) method works.

It's pretty simple.  Every time the system or you call for a repaint of the JPanel, the code in the paintComponent method is executed.

In the paintComponent method, you paint.  Period.  Full stop.  You do **nothing** else in the paintComponent method but paint (draw).

The first thing you do is create a Java object that holds a BufferedImage and a java.awt.Point to hold the x, y position of the BufferedImage.

```
package com.ggl.testing;

import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;

public class ImageLocation {

    private final BufferedImage image;

    private Point imageLocation;

    public ImageLocation(BufferedImage image, Point imageLocation) {
        this.image = image;
        this.imageLocation = imageLocation;
    }

    public Point getImageLocation() {
        return imageLocation;
    }

    public void setImageLocation(Point imageLocation) {
        this.imageLocation = imageLocation;
    }

    public BufferedImage getImage() {
        return image;
    }

}
```

Next, you pass a List of ImageLocation instances to your drawing panel.

Finally, your paintComponent method would look something like this:

```
    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);

        for (ImageLocation imageLocation : imageLocations) {
            Point p = imageLocation.getImageLocation();
            g.drawImage(imageLocation.getImage(), p.x, p.y, this);
        }
    }
```

You create the List of ImageLocation instances somewhere else in your code.  Preferably in a GUI model class.

Answer (score 0):

Because of this :

```
 g.drawImage(imageCount, 0, 0, this);
```

Try to do something as :

```
g.drawImage(imageCount, x, y, this); // x, y should have dynamic values.
```

Hope this Helps.

Comment: I have tried this but it just 'paints the second image at the co-ordinates I put in. But thank you for replying

Answer (score 0):

You can actually use jlabel instead of paintComponent.

```
for (int i = 0; i < docList.size(); i++)
{
    imageCount = docList.get(i);
    JLabel label = new JLabel( new ImageIcon( imageCount ) );
    this.add ( label );
}
```

Comment: I want to use paintComponent as I want to make changes to the image once it is displayed but thank you for replying

Comment: Do you want to make changes to the image on the JPanel itself? or do you want to make changes to docList ?

Comment: I want to be able to select part(s) of the image(s) and then save my changes

Comment: I am assuming you are getting the docList from image files, you edit the images using your image editor and save them right? Then you call JPanel.DisplayImage(); It should repaint the JPanel with new images. But before that, you dispose the old labels. may be you store the labels in a private list and dispose them one by one before adding new ones to the panel.